# Volley request works only after visiting page on desktop browser

Tags: android, http, android-volley

So. My problem is extremely weird (for me). I'm using Volley to send HTTP requests to [this](http://laakeinfo.fi/) site. Using the same code I get 3 types of responses. One is full of weird symbols (WRÄÕÎ¨äxúD©zíÿ&ôÂD...), second one is the page's own error page and the third type is the one I want: the medicine's page.

The only way I have gotten the desired, actual result page, is the weird thing. I'm sending a HTTP GET to the medicine page. Just doing that results in either type 1 or type 2. BUT! When I first click the link (I log it in Android Studio) and go to the page with my desktop's browser (after a few tries usually, the error page pops up sometimes) and THEN click the link in my app again, it loads fine!

I've tried it many many times and it really does seem this is the way it works. I don't restart my app, because I can go back to my results view and click the medicine again. I may click the medicine tens of times always ending up with either the error page or weird symbols, but visiting the page on my desktop and then clicking it in the app again produces always the desired page. What could the problem be? Something about cookies?

The code for the request is as follows:

```
public static void requestWithUrl(final HTTPRequestListener listener, final String url) {
    Log.d("WUT", "URL: " + url);

    final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("WUT", "Got url response");

            try {
                String encoding = "UTF-8";
                String line;
                InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes(encoding));
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, encoding));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.d("WUT", "LINE: " + line);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                listener.onHTTPFailure();
            }

            listener.onFoundSingle("Title", response, true);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("WUT", "Got url error");
            listener.onHTTPFailure();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Host", "www.laakeinfo.fi");
            params.put("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0");
            params.put("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            params.put("Accept-Language", "fi-FI,fi;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
            params.put("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            params.put("Referer", "http://www.laakeinfo.fi/Search.aspx");
            return params;
        }
    };

    request.setTag(TAG);

    queue.add(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems typing the problem open is quite therapeutic, since I found the answer. Simply, when I first request the list of medicines, I get the `Set-Cookie` header's contents in `parseNetworkResponse` and save it. Then when I request the actual page, I set the `Cookie` parameter to the saved cookie and everything works like a dream.